# When using Chrome Driver, I am getting following issue in Selenium

Tags: selenium

Error:

```
Starting ChromeDriver 2.20.353145 (343b531d31eeb933ec778dbcf7081628a1396067) on port 40734
Only local connections are allowed.
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure.
Build info: version: '2.44.0', revision: '76d78cf', time: '2014-10-23 20:03:00'
```

I am unable to open any site by using Chrome Driver in Selenium. Written small code, but it's not working

code:

```
package newproject;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class testchrome {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D:\\selenium\\chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver  driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("http://toolsqa.wpengine.com/automation-practice-form/");
```

Comment: Which jar u used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Downgrade your chrome version to 32 bit , it'll resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think your OS version and chrome driver is not compatible to each other i.e. download same version like 32 bit of both or 64 bit of both.

Comment: I think your OS version and chrome driver is not compatible to each other i.e. download same version like 32 bit of both or 64 bit of both.

Answer (score 0):

Which chrome version are you using?
Chrome driver 2.20 is for Chrome Version 43-48
If your chrome version is current - I assume version 60 or 61
you will get this error I think :D

Comment: I am using chrome version - 60 & used "chromedriver_win32.zip" driver .

Comment: But where can I find driver for this version? as in this site it is saying -"There is no separate 64-bit version of Chromedriver". could you help with any solution for this?

Comment: A simple chrome driver Google search would yield the result... however here you go https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads

Comment: Download the latest version -> 2.32 as of now  dont worry about the bit.. For chrome its ok to use 32 bit